# If a person is dressed up as non-human, and is killed by someone who sincerely believes the victim was not human, who is responsible?

Tags: self-defense, homicide, deception

I've seen several videos about pranks when someone dresses up as a zombie or other kind of monster, to scare people. I would assume that if such an actor dressed up as a monster suddenly attacks someone who out of sheer reflex harms the actor, then the victim of the prank is not culpable if a reasonable person would likely have reacted the same way (please correct me if I'm wrong). But if an actor dressed like a monster just wanders around the street, especially around Halloween, and is attacked by someone, then the attacker is culpable, as no reasonable person would have thought the actor was a threat. (please correct me if I'm wrong)

But let's consider the following scenario:

- **Alice** has a close relative, or boyfriend, or someone she cares deeply about, let's call him **Bob**.
- Alice thinks Bob is too lazy, too comfortable, and wants to enact a scenario to thrill Bob up a little, and make him more self-confident and courageous.
- So Alice hires **Darren** who is a well known stage illusionist / prankster / movie director, to put Bob through a scenario which seems dangerous (but is actually harmless), in order to instill some courage in him.
- Darren creates an elaborate setup, for example fake news broadcasts made specifically for Bob, movie props, a big cast of actors, stage illusion tricks etc. to make it seem like there is an apocalyptic scenario, or that mythical monsters are real, or something similar, and the scenario is so professionally done that most reasonable people would be convinced it is real.
- **Charlie** is one of the actors hired for the show, and is dressed up as a mythical monster (zombie, vampire, lich, whatever) which reasonable people in real life know not to exist, but due to the elaborate setup mentioned above, Bob is gradually convinced is real.
- Bob attacks and kills Charlie, sincerely believing Charlie to be the aforementioned mythical monster. During this, Charlie wasn't actively attacking Bob, it's Bob who sought out and hunted down Charlie.
- Neither Darren, nor Charlie, nor Alice intended this to happen. In fact Darren made all reasonable precautions to prevent such accidents, but despite all these precautions the tragedy still happened. Darren is a professional who organized similar events previously, without a single previous incident.

Who is culpable for Charlie's death? What will the three of them be finally charged with?

*Addendum* : would it be different if Charlie hadn't played the role of a non-human, but a human instead (like an evil necromancer who is responsible for the apocalyptic scenario), so Bob killed him knowing he was a human but believing to be a threat to the whole world, and believing the scenario to be truly apocalyptic?

Comment: There's been cases of people being acquitted after shooting someone believing that the victim was an animal.  eg. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mary_Beth_Harshbarger   https://www.nytimes.com/1990/10/18/us/man-is-acquitted-in-hunting-death.html

Comment: I think an scenario where Charlie was dressed-up as e.g. an angry bear would be simpler than a lich.

Comment: @Ángel +1. It may be too late to change the question without invalidating answers, but I think the legal debate would almost certainly hinge on the "reasonableness" of Bob's belief. "I thought I was killing a bear" is a _vastly_ better defense than "I thought I was killing an undead vampire." Vice versa, if Darren staged an "elaborate setup," frankly, that would seem to place on _Darren_ some of the liability for the mishap (especially if Darren was a licensed professional). Without the vampire business, we could eliminate Darren from the story entirely, right?

Comment: "which seems dangerous (but is actually harmless)" The scenario you describe is too elaborate to be harmless.

Comment: "Who is culpable for Charlie's death? What will the three of them be finally charged with?" Region specific.

Comment: @RossRidge There have even been cases of people getting an [apology](https://www.theguardian.com/world/2006/feb/18/usa.dickcheney) from the person they shot.

Comment: The scenario sounds inspired by [Darren, I mean Derren, Brown's Apocalypse](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt2513228/)

Comment: Asking for a friend...

Comment: A normally reasonable person might panic and act completely unreasonable when they meet a zombie in the street. "I thought I was killing a zombie" is probably a bad defense, but "There was this zombie in the street, carrying someone's torn off arm, so I freaked out completely and shot him" might be better. Might be "temporary insanity".

Comment: It's been 33 years and I still think about this case: https://newengland.com/today/living/new-england-history/karenwood/

Comment: I would submit that the goal of improving self confidence was accomplished...

Answer (score 27):

Laws on self-defense vary greatly from nation to nation. Generally, one cannot *hunt down* a hypothetical threat but one can *defend against* an actual threat or even a *mistakenly assumed* actual threat where no actual threat exists. **Alice** set it up so that **Bob** would feel threatened.

In many jurisdictions, the **self-defense** defense for homicide rests on the state of the mind of the suspect, insofar as it can be determined, and failing that on a "reasonable person" standard.

- Presumably **Bob** genuinely felt threatened by **Charlie** and says so afterwards. "I thought he/it/whatever was trying to harm me. I didn't know it was a harmless actor." Just how much harm Bob needs to make self-defense stick varies from jurisdiction to jurisdiction. It could be fear of imminent, serious bodily harm, or fear of being victimized in any sort of crime (*stand your ground* laws).
  As the comment by user6726 points out, just protraying a zombie or whatever isn't enough, there has to be threat to Bob.
- **Bob** cannot hunt **Charlie** down because Charlie "is" an evil lich or whatever. Bob can defend himself against attacks by Charlie and (in some jurisdictions) against intrusions by Charlie in his property. So it makes a difference if Bob hunts in his own backyard or further afield.
- The well-documented and extensive efforts by Alice and Darren to fool **Bob** should support Bob's statement. Say the court/jury believes that it was reasonable (or at least "not entirely unreasonable") for Bob to be afraid.
- Since the perceived self-defense would apply *even if* Bob thought the attacker was human, thinking that it was non-human should make little difference. Except that it would further showcase the degree to which Bob was fooled to see a threat.
- If the whole endeavor by **Alice** and **Darren** broke laws, the death *might* fall into felony homicide in some jurisdictions. This one could come to technicalities because Bob wasn't their accomplice. Otherwise, Darren's track record might prevent the two from being charged for negligent homicide.

Consider the well-publicized cases where either the police or civilians shot unarmed people, and say that they *thought* the victim was armed and a threat to them. If doesn't matter if the victim drew a gun or a wallet, it matters if the shooter can make his or her fears plausible enough.

Comment: Are you proposing that an unreasonable belief can support justifiable homicide? Not in Washington: RCW 9A.16.050 requires *reasonable* grounds.

Comment: @user6726, If Bob thought that Charlie was threatening *because* he was a zombie, that would apply. But not if Bob thought that Charlie was threatening *and* a zombie. See my first bullet point regarding perceived threats.

Comment: A reasonable person would know that zombies are not real, therefore the acts on display are not real. E.g. if you see an apparent assault *but* also see a film crew, it is not reasonable to believe that the "victim" is being attacked.

Comment: @user6726, right, but if I see an apparent assault by someone who looks like a zombie and no film crew, I should disregard the makeup/skin condition/whatever and act as if it was a human attacker. Otherwise all muggers would dress up as mummies.

Comment: @user6726, I appended a sentence to the first bullet point.

Comment: This is a great summary, but I think a crucial point is missing: if Bob wasn't currently under attack by Charlie, but he specifically went out to hunt down the "monster", like hoping he can catch it off-guard, couldn't then the prosecution argue against self-defense? In a normal situation if a mugger physically assaults you, you have the right to self defense, but if you just notice someone on the street who mugged you yesterday, you don't have the right to go up to him and stab him in the back.

Comment: @vsz, that's a point. Look at the text in the first bullet point, should I make that even clearer?

Comment: I feel like this is missing something. If I hunt down and kill a lion, I am not guilty of homicide even if self-defense does not apply. (Guilty of a felony very probably, but not of homicide.) I think this needs to be addressed to handle the question "What will the three of them be finally charged with?": in case self-defense is found not to apply, what should be the charge for someone who hunted down and killed a (they believed) non-human zombie/vampire/lich? Does it depend on the fake news reports fed to Bob (e.g., if he was led to believe that zombies are mindless)?

Comment: @CharlesStaats, zombies and liches are ex-human, and the law usually does not allow a layperson to determine death (which would make it tampering with a corpse, instead).

Comment: @o.m. "I didn't tamper with the corpse, the corpse tampered with me!"

Comment: And if the deception involved showing Bob a falsified death certificate for Charlie's character? Then (as far as Bob can tell) determination of death has been made by a licensed professional, rather than by Bob himself. Would this absolve him from a homicide charge for hunting down Charlie's walking "corpse"?

Comment: @CharlesStaats, I guess that depends very much on the jurisdiction and the trial. If this "hypothetical" really happened it would be a media circus.

Comment: Any country that has such laws should be considered a humanitary crisis at least. And probably (like the us) the axes of evil for allowing violence on purpose nad not banning weaponry.

Comment: I would argue that Bob would be at the very least charged with some form of negligence, most likely negligent homicide. A person is found negligent if they do or fail to do something that a "reasonable person" would do or fail to do in a given situation, and I don't think it would be hard for any prosecution to argue that a reasonable person wouldn't believe in the supernatural to the extent of hunting and killing. Self-defense situations might throw a wrench in that approach, but as the question is worded, it's pretty clear that Bob sought out Charlie so self-defense doesn't apply regardless.

Comment: To make things even more confusing/interesting, there are two things to consider here: criminal charges brought by the state (homicide, etc), and civil charges brought by the deceased's family (wrongful death).  Someone could be considered responsible for the death in a criminal case but not in a civil case, or vice versa.

Answer (score 8):

Something like [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9rDD5iMVt9g)?

**Darren organised a situation where he knew a fight or flight situation was likely - it is his responsibility to ensure the safety of all involved.** This would also include a debrief afterwards to ensure no lasting mental damage to Bob.

The setting would need to be safe.

- If Darren had left a dangerous weapon for Bob to get hold of then it is their fault.
- If Darren didn't have security ready to step in at a moment's notice it would be his fault.

Answer (score 0):

Defense against a monster or mythical creature based upon the good faith belief that someone really is a monster or mythical creature, would fail as a matter of law. The same analysis would apply where the human threat that someone believed that they were defending themselves against was purely supernatural.

The case would be evaluated under the standards applicable to self-defense against humans who cannot use supernatural powers, because no reasonable person could believe (as a definitional matter of law) that these were really monsters or mythical creatures or supernatural powers exist (unless an ordinary insanity defense could be proven which would have to show the existence of a pre-existing mental illness, typically schizophrenia, that made someone hallucinate about what was true or made them unable to distinguish between right and wrong). Self-defense is evaluated from an objective reasonableness standard, not a purely subjective one.

On the other hand, if the defense was against an ordinary dangerous animal, the person who used force could argue successfully to a jury (and leave the jury to decide) that they reasonably believed that it was a dangerous animal and that if it was, that their use of force was justified.

Also, even if their use of force against an apparent actual ordinary dangerous animal was not justified under that standard, they could argue that they lacked the requisite intent for a crime such as assault or homicide against a person, and might be guilty instead of the crime of attempted illegal hunting, or unjustified discharge of a firearm in public.

Comment: What if one knew the monster was not real and assume it was in fact a human BUT the hidden identity plus menacing nature justified the defendant's use of force.  After all, we are talking about the most dangerous game here.

Comment: @hszmv "The case would be evaluated under the standards applicable to self-defense against humans who cannot use supernatural powers"

Comment: Yeah, my first read through had me thinking more of the 2016 Killer Clown Sightings in the U.S. and what if someone reacted defensively to the perceived threat.

Comment: *"no reasonable person could believe "* - do you really think no reasonable person could be convinced if a team of professionals conspiring with his family members did a long con, built up an elaborate setup, gradually prepared the scene, by manipulating the information received, using gaslighting and other manipulation techniques, gradually isolated the subject from the outside world so that at the end all people around were in the conspiracy, then used professional stage magic and special effects to fake the supernatural?

Comment: @vsz When the law uses the term "reasonable person" this is legalese code for not considering the subjective beliefs of the actual person in that situation and instead looking to what a typical person off the street would do in that situation. It is also a subtle but intentional tool that legal language uses to marginalize certain beliefs in certain contexts even if they are actually widely held. It doesn't literally mean, in a legal context, that no person is generally reasonable could actually believe something or do something. A "reasonable person" is more rational than real typical people.

Comment: @vsz continued . . . note that I state "because no reasonable person could believe (as a definitional matter of law)". In other words, the "reasonable person" standard is a somewhat aspirational legal standard, rather than a standard determined as a matter of fact finding based upon empirical reality. It is what a person who lives up to the standards that the law expects of that person would do. Reasonable people don't believe impossible things. Reasonable people weight costs and benefits in light of probabilities. Reasonable people aren't indoctrinated.

Comment: @ohwilleke : but if your whole world was built up around you in a certain way, than for you that would be the empirical reality (think of the The Truman Show as a very extreme example). Would a reasonable person in that position be expected to instantly know that that reality is not the "real" reality?

Comment: @vsz The intent of the law is to protect ordinary people from people who are in these distorted situations.

Comment: @ohwilleke : you mean from the victims of such a deception, not from the perpetrators of the deception? What do you base that assertion on?   (and in my example one of the perpetrators of the deception was killed by the victim of the deception, there were no "ordinary" uninvolved people in it)

Comment: General discussion of distinction between objective and subjective reasonableness. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subjective_and_objective_standard_of_reasonableness and https://www.justia.com/criminal/defenses/imperfect-self-defense/  Typical academic discussion. https://www.jstor.org/stable/10.1525/nclr.2008.11.1.51 and https://heinonline.org/HOL/LandingPage?handle=hein.journals/ajcl26&div=7&id=&page=

Comment: Worth considering in case you haven't heard of it before:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_War_of_the_Worlds_(1938_radio_drama)

Comment: I don’t think you can say a reasonable person must be an atheist that doesn’t believe in any sort of supernatural entity as a matter of law.  https://www.virginialawreview.org/articles/can-the-reasonable-person-be-religious-accommodation-and-the-common-law/. Not that necessarily gets someone off the hook for killing such a supernatural being.

Answer (score -2):

This answer is based on my recollection of a book I once read. I no longer have access to the book, and I don't remember clearly which jurisdiction it applied to, but I believe it is the United States.

In general you are legally allowed to respond with deadly force if:

- You are in a place where you do not have to flee. Called the [castle doctrine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Castle_doctrine), it usually applies to your house. If someone intrudes into your house, you are allowed to respond with force, including with deadly force, as opposed to flee.
- If the castle doctrine does not apply, then you are still allowed to respond with deadly force if you genuinely believe your life is in danger. For example, if someone attacks you with a gun or knife, you are allowed to kill them. Note the limitations: as the gun is being drawn you are allowed to kill them; if they shoot, miss, drop the gun and run, you are *NOT* allowed to kill them.

Note one thing about these laws: they don't apply to only humans. You are also allowed to kill e.g. a dog if it attacks you in your house.

The upshot is, Bob is allowed to kill Charlie if 1) Charlie is unlawfully in his abode, or 2) Bob legitimately believes his life is in danger. Therefore the key part of your question is this one:

> During this, Charlie wasn't actively attacking Bob, it's Bob who sought out and hunted down Charlie.

If Bob is doing this then neither 1) nor 2) apply. What he did is illegal, and he is culpable.

Comment: Some jurisdictions allow you to lethal force for the protection of others, if you believe that they're at risk of lethal injury. Hunting down a zombie to stop of a zombie apocalypse would probably count, though I'm not a lawyer.

Comment: You aren't "allowed to kill them". You are allowed to use lethal force, which may cause death. If you shoot them and they drop, you can't shoot them again to secure a kill.

Comment: @forest : but you are (under certain circumstances and in certain jurisdictions) allowed to kill wild animals, even if it's not in self-defense.